Unable to Install TensorFlow 2.16.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 with Python 3.10.12
I am trying to install TensorFlow 2.16.1 on my Ubuntu 22.04 system using pip, but I keep encountering an error saying that no matching distribution is found. Below are the details of my system:

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Python Version: 3.10.12
Architecture: x86_64
Pip Version: 24.0

When I try to use the command pip install tensorflow, it installs version 2.13.1, but I need version 2.16.1.
Here are the commands and outputs from my terminal:
(base) aria@laptop:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

(base) aria@laptop:~$ python --version
Python 3.10.12

(base) aria@laptop:~$ uname -m
x86_64

(base) aria@laptop:~$ pip --version
pip 24.0 from /home/aria/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

(base) aria@laptop:~$ pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.16.1
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.16.1 (from versions: 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.3.0, 2.3.1, 2.3.2, 2.3.3, 2.3.4, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2, 2.4.3, 2.4.4, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, 2.5.2, 2.5.3, 2.6.0rc0, 2.6.0rc1, 2.6.0rc2, 2.6.0, 2.6.1, 2.6.2, 2.6.3, 2.6.4, 2.6.5, 2.7.0rc0, 2.7.0rc1, 2.7.0, 2.7.1, 2.7.2, 2.7.3, 2.7.4, 2.8.0rc0, 2.8.0rc1, 2.8.0, 2.8.1, 2.8.2, 2.8.3, 2.8.4, 2.9.0rc0, 2.9.0rc1, 2.9.0rc2, 2.9.0, 2.9.1, 2.9.2, 2.9.3, 2.10.0rc0, 2.10.0rc1, 2.10.0rc2, 2.10.0rc3, 2.10.0, 2.10.1, 2.11.0rc0, 2.11.0rc1, 2.11.0rc2, 2.11.0, 2.11.1, 2.12.0rc0, 2.12.0rc1, 2.12.0, 2.12.1, 2.13.0rc0, 2.13.0rc1, 2.13.0rc2, 2.13.0, 2.13.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.16.1

Additionally, I also tried to install TensorFlow using the wheel file from this page by executing the following command:
(base) aria@laptop:~/Downloads$ pip install tensorflow_cpu-2.16.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl
ERROR: tensorflow_cpu-2.16.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I have verified that my system meets the necessary requirements for installing TensorFlow. However, it appears that TensorFlow 2.16.1 is not found in the available versions, and the wheel file installation also fails.
I do not have a GPU, so I am trying to install the CPU version of TensorFlow.
I would appreciate any guidance on how to resolve this issue. Is there a specific repository I need to add, or is there another way to install TensorFlow 2.16.1 on my setup?
Thank you!

Also you seem to have two python versions installed: 3.8 and 3.10.

@Dr.Snoopy my os is ubuntu, why would I need wheel for windows?

Ah right, got confused, then the problem is that pip is using python 3.8, you have two python versions installed (3.8 and 3.10).

@Dr.Snoopy yeah, you are right! python versions are conflicted! Now my problem is solved! Thanks

Try running directly without --upgrade
Like this:
pip install tensorflow


It installs version 2.13.1 but I need version 2.16.1

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Yes, there was a problem installing tensorflow 2.16 for Ubuntu.
Please see the links for the solution.
https://discuss.tensorflow.org/t/tensorflow-version-2-16-just-released/23140
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/63362
If you want to use 2.16.1 and you use conda then the easiest fix is with activated env:
mkdir -p ${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d

create file in ${CONDA_PREFIX}/etc/conda/activate.d/fix_gpu.sh with content below:
NVIDIA_DIR=$(dirname $(dirname $(python -c "import nvidia.cudnn;print(nvidia.cudnn.__file__)")))
for dir in $NVIDIA_DIR/*; do
    if [ -d "$dir/lib" ]; then
        export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$dir/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
    fi
done


This is answering a different problem, the links are not for the same problem in the question.
